# How many people now watch the live event

Tags: flash-media-server

I use livepkgr to show liveevents to my viewers. Now I'd like to show to them how many people now watch the live event.

Please advise me.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Number of connected users available in FMS. Supposing you can customize your player, then it is possible to call FMS for connected users each 10 seconds and show number in player.